# How can I change html images into a slider when the display with is under 600px?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

So I am  designing a webpage, and I have three images aligned next to each other:

html :

```html
<div id="imgs">
  <img src="img/img_2.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="img/img_1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="img/img_0.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

css :

```css
#imgs img { 
   width: 29%; 
   margin: 1.5%; 
}
```

On desktop I want to keep the three images next to each other but when on mobile I want then into a slider.

Comment: Have a look at https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/carousel.

Comment: Do you have any more code you can show?

Comment: The css I am using :
#imgs img {
    width: 29%;
    margin: 1.5%;
}
and the box-sizing is set to border-box and everything is in an container {width: 10%; margin: auto}

Comment: Have you written any javascript to try and get a slider working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to make two elements and display the first one if the width of the page is > 600px. Else you display the other.

```html
<div id="imgs-flex">
  <img src="img/img_2.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="img/img_1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="img/img_0.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div id="img-mobile">
  <img src="img/img_2.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="img/img_1.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="img/img_0.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

And then in the CSS :

```css
#img-flex{
  display: flex;
}
#img-mobile{
  display: none;
}

/* You use Media Queries for the responsive */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
   #img-mobile{
      display: block;
   } 
   #img-flex{
      display: none;
   }
}
```

And you add Javascript to do your slider.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `display: flex;` and a media query for with a min-max?

Comment: I've thought about it, but this wouldn't solve my problem. I think I can get it working using jquery

Answer (score 0):

If the screen is smaller then 600px the three images are displayed one below the other. Larger than 600px are all images placed side by side.

I hope this is what you are searching for...

```css
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 50%; /* for fullscreen take 100% */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.zdnet.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/stackoverflow.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%;">
   </div>
     <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.zdnet.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/stackoverflow.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
   </div>
     <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.zdnet.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/stackoverflow.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%">
   </div>
</div>
```